# Pyperclip doesn't copy to the clipboard outside of shell

Tags: python, pyperclip

I used

```
pip install pyperclip
```

to install the package. when I use it in a script, eg.:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('somestring')
pyperclip.paste()
```

it would return `'somestring'`

my issue is that I wanna use it to paste elsewhere but the shell, it acts like there's nothing to paste. What could be wrong?
(I use linux system)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue try pip3 install may be it work for you
if not use `xclip`. this is werid shell command

```
import subprocess


subprocess.call(["xclip","-o"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on a Windows computer, perhaps the module is not supported on other things besides the python IDE as pyperclip.paste() would not work on anything other than that. My workaround was to

```
import pyautogui
```

hover over the spot you want to paste. Then in the terminal or IDE use:

```
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

to display your mouse's x and y coordinates, then use those coordinates with:

```
pyautogui.click(x, y)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

to literally ctrl+v.